# Django get_queryset filter objects on pk

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

So I have these models **client** and **progress**.
I've mixed the Create and ListView but I only want to show progress data for the current client. I accomplished this with a hardcoded PK but when I try to make it dynamically I only get errors like

```
Field 'id' expected a number but got <property object at 0x10ee5f890>.
```

models.py

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...

class Progress(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

views.py

```
class ProgressClient(generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'pages/clients/progress/index.html'
    model = Progress
    form_class = ProgressForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['object_list'] = Progress.objects.filter(client__id=1)
        return super(ProgressClient, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('clients/progress/<slug:slug>/<int:pk>', login_required(views.ProgressClient.as_view(), login_url='/login'), name="progress_clients"),
]
```

I've tried things like

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    kwargs['object_list'] = Progress.objects.filter(client__id=Client.pk)
    return super(ProgressClient, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    client_pk = self.kwargs.get('client_id')
    kwargs['object_list'] = Progress.objects.filter(client__id=client_pk)
    return super(ProgressClient, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Can you share the related `path(..)` from `urls.py`?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This primary key is a parameter of the path. You can access these with `self.kwargs`, so you can filter with:

```
class ProgressClient(generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'pages/clients/progress/index.html'
    model = Progress
    form_class = ProgressForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['object_list'] = Progress.objects.filter(client_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return super(ProgressClient, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Well feeling pretty dumb right now.. but thank you!